# Closed form or estimation for summation $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_{2}{n-1}}{(2^{i} \log_{2}{(n / {2^{i})}})}$

Tags: summation, logarithms, asymptotics

I came up with this summation for an algorithm, but cannot figure out how to calculate or estimate the answer:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_{2}{n-1}}{\left(2^{i} \log_{2}{\left(\frac{n}{2^{i}}\right)}\right)}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Hint** Use $\log_2 \left(2^{-i} n\right)=\log_2 \left(2^{-i} \right)+\log_2(n)$ and simplify

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That helped. Thanks!